# Can hg log show only the ancestors of a given revision?

Tags: mercurial

One thing I really miss moving from svn to mercurial is that mercurial's hg log command insists on showing all history rather than only the history of my current working revision.

For example, I'm working on a repo with a lot of check-ins to another head within my branch, and the first 20 log entries have nothing to do with my line of development.

There are a bunch of options to hg log, but...
--rev shows the revision asked for but not its ancestors
--branch doesn't work because the active head is in the same branch as mine
--prune removes all ancestors of the other head, even if they're also my ancestors
--user doesn't work because I'm not the only user in this line of development

I guess I could hg strip, but that seems like overkill...

Thoughts?
Ryan

Comment: look at revsets http://selenic.com/pipermail/mercurial-devel/2010-June/021638.html

Comment: @tonfa: posted an answer using revsets.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you've got Mercurial 1.6 or later, you can use [*revsets*](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/revsets) to do this:

```
hg log --rev "ancestors(.)"
hg log --rev "reverse(ancestors(.))"  # Output in the same order as vanilla hg log
```

Comment: Awesome! Just a quick note -- bash wants that enclosed in quotes

Comment: @ryan: I'm on Windows, where they're not required (at least for this case).

Comment: thanks! was looking for a way to show a graphical log for N revisions starting from a particular version.  hg normally complains if you tell it to `--follow` and want the graphical output, but works great using `ancestors(rev#)`, this is exactly what I wanted: `hg log -r "ancestors(.)" -l 20 -G`

Comment: That's awesome! Where can I learn about the possible syntax for the --rev argument? Tried reading up on the hg book but it's too short a command to search for...

Comment: Not to worry - I re-read it and realised it was the revsets thing. Updated the answer slightly to link to them.

Answer (score 21):

I know revision sets is all the rage these days (`hg log -r "::."`), but the little-known `--follow` flag lets you do what you want using any version of Mercurial. The [`hg log` help](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#log) says (my emphasis in bold):

> [...] Use `-f/--follow` with a filename to follow history across renames and
>   copies. **`--follow` without a filename will only show ancestors or
>   descendants of the starting revision.** [...]
>
> If no revision range is specified, the default is tip:0 **unless `--follow` is
>   set, in which case the working directory parent is used as the starting
>   revision.** [...]

So, in other words, adding `-f` will do the trick for you. You can add `-f` to your defaults:

```
[defaults]
log = -f
```

or better yet, you can create an alias for this:

```
[alias]
logf = log -f
```

That avoids changing a core command like `hg log`, which will probably confuse you or your colleagues sooner or later.

Comment: if I hadn't already used my answer on this post this would have earned it. Simple and does exactly what I asked for. Thanks!

Comment: Ryan: thanks, I just wanted to make sure that people also knew about the simple solution :)

Answer (score 1):

As Niall C said, you can do this from the command line using revsets:

```
hg log --rev "ancestors(.)"
```

Also, if you have TortoiseHg, you can filter the revision graph in the Repository Explorer using the radio buttons marked "All", "Tagged", "Ancestry", "Parents", "Heads", "Merges" and so on just above your history. In this case, you would select the revision whose ancestry you are interested in and then choose the "Ancestry" option.